# Get Google Plus user access_token in Azure webapp server

Tags: node.js, azure, express, oauth, google-plus

I have set up an Azure webapp successfully running Node.JS with Express and added a Google Plus authentication using the built in Azure Google "Authentication / Authorization". The auth process works just fine using SSL and and I am able to get users authenticated.

Now,
I know the auth process is calling https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback with the user access_token for future API calls but in this case Azure "intercepts" it (instead of what will normally happen - I would get it on my won server).

The question is - Is there any why to get and use this token on the server?

I have tried to add a route to the .auth/login/google/callback and somewho get the code

```
router.get('/.auth/login/google/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("CALLBACK");
    next();
});
```

to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auth info from google+ will be set in request headers. If you list your request headers in a router function like:
`res.send(JSON.stringify(req.headers));`

You can the auth info are set in the headers with the prefix `x-ms-token-google-`.

Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-authentication/ for more details.

Meanwhile, you can simply issue a GET to the /.auth/me endpoint on your site for retrieving additional user information as well as any tokens required for graph calls. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/ for details.